# Is it a TensorFlow Best Practice for loss functions be callable (in the form of a function)? Other advantages besides Eager Execution compatibility?

Tags: tensorflow

Eager Execution requires any loss passed to any optimizer to be callabe, ie, in the form of a function.

So this is OK

```
def loss_function():
    return tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                               labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))
```

but this is NOT ok

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                               labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))
```

And will raise this error

```
`loss` passed to Optimizer.compute_gradients should be a function when eager execution is enabled.
```

I've noticed that usually when a new Tensorflow feature requires some sort of practice, there are usually multiple benefits associated with that requirement even when not using that feature. For example, Eager execution also requires `get_variable`, to define variables. And as far as I can tell, there is no reason to use `variable` over `get_variable`

So are there any other advantages of having a loss function be callable outside of using Eager Execution?

Comment: Just to clarify, eager execution does *not* require using `get_variable`; the preferred way to create a variable when executing eagerly is to create a `tf.contrib.eager.Variable` object directly. Also note that `tf.contrib.eager.Variable` s are compatible with graph building.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Why is it preferred to use `tf.contrib.eager.Variable` ? Is there an advantage over 'get_variable` ?

Comment: When eager execution is enabled, TensorFlow has no notion of collections. So, instead of stashing variables in a global collection and looking them up by name later, you're meant to directly construct variables and store them in, e.g., a Python class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the loss issue (Akshay summed up the variable issue in the question comments):

When graph building, `Tensor`s can behave like [futures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises), and this is the way the `Optimizer` methods use it. Then this future can be evaluated many times in the training loop and the evaluation monitored to produce the gradient (which works by adding a bunch of ops to the graph which look at intermediate values).

Tensors are literal values when executing eagerly, so to get the same behavior it needs to be wrapped in a function (which is then run with a `tf.GradientTape` active to trace the gradient).

As for whether it's a best practice, new TensorFlow code being graph/eager agnostic is a good thing, although writing agnostic training loops is often more effort than it's worth. In general using Tensors as futures can be a bit harder to reason about.