# `loss` passed to Optimizer.compute_gradients should be a function when eager execution is enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow, I just started learning and understanding it.
I am working on `neural style transfer` problem and I am using tensorflow `version 1.14`.

I am getting an error **loss passed to Optimizer.compute_gradients should be a function when eager execution is enabled**.

I tried to solve the problem by using TensorFlow graph instead of `eager execution`, but it's not working. I want to use `eager execution` because it looks like a more pythonic way.

here is my code, sorry for putting whole code here, please suggest corrections in my code.

```
import scipy
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from scipy import misc
from skimage.transform import resize
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

tf.enable_eager_execution()
print('Eager execution {}'.format(tf.executing_eagerly()))

content_path = '800px-Green_Sea_Turtle_grazing_seagrass.jpg'
style_path = '800px-The_Great_Wave_off_Kanagawa.jpg'

content_img = plt.imread(content_path)
plt.imshow(content_img)
style_img = plt.imread(style_path)
plt.imshow(style_img)

MEANS = np.array([123.68, 116.779, 103.939]).reshape((1,1,1,3))
content_img = resize(content_img, (552,800,3)) #resized content img because style img has shape (552,800,3)

content_img = np.array(content_img)
content_img = np.reshape(content_img, ((1,)+content_img.shape))
style_img = np.array(style_img)
style_img = np.reshape(style_img, ((1,)+style_img.shape))

noise_img= np.random.uniform(-20,20,(1,552,800,3)).astype('float32')
generated_img = noise_img*0.6 + content_img*0.4
plt.imshow(generated_img[0])

content_img = content_img-MEANS
style_img = style_img-MEANS

model = VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

def compute_content_cost(act_content_img, act_generated_img):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(act_content_img-act_generated_img))

def gram_matrix(A):
    gram = tf.matmul(A, tf.transpose(A))
    return gram

def style_loss_one_layer(act_style_img, act_generated_img):
    m,n_H,n_W,n_C = tf.shape(act_generated_img)               #act_generated_img.get_shape().as_list()
    gram_act_style_img = gram_matrix(act_style_img)
    gram_generated_img = gram_matrix(act_generated_img)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(gram_act_style_img-gram_generated_img))*(1/(4*n_C**2*(n_H*n_W)**2))

content_layer = ['block5_conv2']
style_layers = [('block1_conv1',0.2), 
                ('block2_conv1',0.2),
                ('block3_conv1',0.2),
                ('block4_conv1',0.2),
                ('block5_conv1',0.2)]

def compute_style_cost(model, style_layers):
    style_cost = total_style_cost = 0
    for layer, coeff in style_layers:
        act_style_img = model.get_layer(layer).output
        act_generated_img = model.get_layer(layer).output
        style_cost += style_loss_one_layer(act_style_img, act_generated_img)
        total_style_cost += coeff*style_cost 
    return total_style_cost

def compute_total_cost(J_content, J_style, alpha=10, beta=40):
    J = (alpha*tf.cast(J_content, tf.float64)) + (beta*J_style)
    return J

act_generated_img = model.get_layer('block5_conv2').output
act_content_img = model.get_layer('block5_conv2').output

J_content = compute_content_cost(act_content_img=act_content_img, act_generated_img=act_generated_img)
print(J_content)
J_style = compute_style_cost(model, style_layers=style_layers)
print(J_style)

J_total_cost = compute_total_cost(J_content, J_style, alpha=10, beta=40)
print(J_total_cost)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(2.0)

train_step = optimizer.minimize(J_total_cost)        #**getting error here**
```

Comment: Hello Vikas,
Can you please share the links of the Images which you are using. Because, when I have downloaded the Images and trying to reproduce the issue, I am getting other errors. Once I could reproduce your Error, I can help you in resolution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I am following a blog from `medium.com` and took images from there, here is link of blog https://medium.com/tensorflow/neural-style-transfer-creating-art-with-deep-learning-using-tf-keras-and-eager-execution-7d541ac31398

Comment: Can you refer the link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50806180/11530462 and let us know if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The above error is mainly caused when you are trying to use TensorFlow 1.x but the system is running tensor 2.0.

Initialise the TensorFlow using the code below to ensure you are trying to use the version 1.0

> import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

You can make the system disable that behaviour by the below command after the initialisers.

> tf.disable_v2_behavior()

Comment: @vikas-gautam please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Good solution for me!

Comment: This is just disabling the eager execution. Definitely not the solution.