# Defining a callable "loss" function

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, eager-execution, tensorflow1.15

I am trying to optimize a loss function (defined using evidence lower bound) with `tf.train.AdamOptimizer.minimize()` on Tensorflow version `1.15.2` with eager execution enabled. I tried the following:

```
learning_rate = 0.01
optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optim.minimize(loss)
```

and got the following : `RuntimeError: "loss" passed to Optimizer.compute_gradients should be a function when eager execution is enabled.`

This works fine if I disable eager execution but since I need to save a tensorflow variable as a `numpy` array so I need eager execution enabled. The documentation mentions that when eager execution is enabled, the loss must be a **callable**. So the loss function should be defined in a way that it takes no inputs but gives out loss. I am not exactly sure how do I achieve such a thing.

I tried `train_op = optim.minimize(lambda: loss)` but got `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables [] and loss <function <lambda> at 0x7f3c67a93b00>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`loss\` passed to Optimizer.compute\_gradients should be a function when eager execution is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858219/loss-passed-to-optimizer-compute-gradients-should-be-a-function-when-eager-exe)

Comment: @Xiddoc Sadly, no! As I mentioned I am using Tensorflow 1.15.2 so I do not need to disable TF v2 behaviour

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?